# C# Raising event to inherited classes only

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have a generic user control:

```
public partial class SearchBoxGeneric<T> : UserControl
{
    protected class RecordFoundEventArgs
    {
        public T Record { get; private set; }

        public RecordFoundEventArgs(T record)
        {
            this.Record = record;
        }
    }
    protected event EventHandler<RecordFoundEventArgs> RecordFound;

    //Called from search button
    public void Find()
    {
        //1. Search for record in the db
        //2. Raise event to derived classes
    }
}
```

I have user controls that inherit from this generic control. Now when I search for a record from the db, I would like to the raise the event to the inherited control.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why is your event defined as static?

Comment: You can just raise the event, or am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To raise an event you use same code you would use for a public event:

```
public void Find()
{
    T record = FindRecordCore();
    if (record != default(T))
    {
        var recordFound = RecordFound;
        if (recordFound != null)
            recordFound(this, new RecordFoundEventArgs(record));
    }
}
```

To follow *normal* pattern for events you should add a specific `OnXyz` method:

```
protected virtual void OnRecordFound(RecordFoundEventArgs e)
{
    var recordFound = RecordFound;
    if (recordFound != null)
        recordFound(this, e);
}
```

Invoked like this:

```
public void Find()
{
    T record = FindRecordCore();
    if (record != default(T))
        OnRecordFound(new RecordFoundEventArgs(record));
}
```

**BUT** What I would consider is if here an event is needed. Why don't you simply use a protected method? Events are notifications (or *connection points*) for external classes, derived classes can always simply override a class method. A `protected` event is something *strange* and you should ask yourself the reason for that:

```
protected virtual void OnRecordFound(T record)
{
    // Derived classes will handle "event" here
}

public void Find()
{
    T record = FindRecordCore();
    if (record != default(T))
        OnRecordFound(record);
}
```

Even if event was `public` if you follow *normal* events pattern (and you have a `protected OnRecordFound` method) usually derived classes should override `OnRecordFound()` and event `RecordFound` is used by external entities.

Answer (score 0):

Events are normally fired so someone else can be notified when something happens.

```
public class SearchBox {
    public event EventHandler<RecordFoundEventArgs> RecordFound;

    protected virtual void OnRecordFound(RecordFoundEventArgs e) {
        var recordFound = RecordFound;
        if (recordFound != null) {
            recordFound(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void Find() {
        // ...

        // Fire event
        OnRecordFound(new RecordFoundEventArgs(...));
    }
}

// Usage
var searchBox = new SearchBox();
searchBox.RecordFound += (s, e) => { ... };
searchBox.Find();   // trigger the eventhandler we just defined
```

But if you have a derived class, it is more common to override the `OnRecordFound` method, and add the logic you need to run there.

```
public class SpecialSearchBox: SearchBox {
    protected override void OnRecordFound(RecordFoundEventArgs e) {
        base.OnRecordFound(e);

        // Do something extra
    }
}
```

Now whenever the event is fired, the logic in our derived class is run automatically.

If you have defined your event just to notify a derived class, it is probably easier to just define a virtual method that you can call from the base class.